# Run .exe from another app and enter values automatically

Tags: c#, .net, cmd

I want to run .exe file from another app, which is console app in .NET Core. When the app is open I want to write input to console from my code. Something like this:

```
var cmd = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("myApp.exe");
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            cmd.Start();
            cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("MyName"); // this should be entered in console as username
```

So I specify username from my code, instead of writing it to console manually. Code above is not working for me. Is there a way to do this?

[enter username](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdX9l.png)

Comment: Can you please add some minimal code for myApp.exe? It's tough to say what exactly isn't working at the moment. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Off the top of my head, you can try cmd.StandardInput.Flush() after the writeline command.

Answer (score 0):

You're first starting the Process and then you're manipulating the startup arguments. You need to start the process afterwards.

use something like this instead:

```cs
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false; //required to redirect standart input/output

// redirects on your choice
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

startInfo.FileName = ...app path to execute...;
startInfo.Arguments = ...argumetns if required...;

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();

process.StandardInput.WriteLine(...write whatever you want...);
```

[source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/46c91711-755f-48fa-a4a8-92956082218f/howto-launch-process-and-write-to-its-stdin?forum=netfxbcl)

Answer (score 0):

You need redirect standard input. Create ProcessStartInfo structure, then start a process and after process started write to the process standart input

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = pathToApplication,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false
};

Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);

var writer = process.StandardInput;

writer.WriteLine("MyName");

Console.ReadLine();
```